# Azure Data Factory copy from one DataLake to another DataLake

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I need to build a pipeline that is able to copy from one DataLake to another one, but so far by googleing around I couldn't find anything related to it, can anyone please point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Using the copy wizard in data factory v1 you are able to copy from one data lake store to another nice and easily.

I'm not sure if this is available yet for v2 in wizard form, but should be fine to do configured by hand.

Comment: thanks for the replay, but I don't know how or where to get the Service principal id

Comment: Hi, probably best starting that as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Use Data Lake v2 copy activity with Azure Data Lake Store DataSet.

This way you could copy files from one data lake to another.